# React HashRouter is having two hash symbols '#' when using Redirect component's pathname

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

I'm using `"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"` for my application. I have used its `HashRouter` to handle my routing. My root route should redirect to a specific route along with the existing query string. The issue I'm having is that once I use the `Redirect` component's `pathName` it adds two '#' symbols to my URL.

**Current behaviour:** `mydomain.org/myApp#/?someParam=someValue` => `mydomain.org/myApp#/CompA#/?someParam=someValue`

**Expected behaviour:** `mydomain.org/myApp#/?someParam=someValue` => `mydomain.org/myApp#/CompA/?someParam=someValue`

Here is what I have done

```tsx
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, HashRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const App: React.FC<any> = (props: any) => {

  return (
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact key="/" path="/">
            <RedirectComp to="/CompA" />
          </Route>
          <Route exact key="/CompA" path="/CompA">
            <CompA />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
  );
};

const RedirectComp: React.FC<any> = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <Redirect to={{ ...location, pathname: props.to }} />
  );
}
```

The reason I'm using a custom component to redirect is to preserve the queryString when redirecting. That's why I cannot use `<Redirect to="/CompA" />`.

Is there a cleaner way of achieving this without having to do a string search in the `Location.hash` and updating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the global [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object instead of the location that Redirect expects. Inside `RedirectComp`, use the [`useLocation()`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook to get the location. Both `Location` objects have a hash field, but they do not match since you are using `HashRouter`.

Additionally, if all you want to do is preserve the query string, you only need to include the `search` field from the [`Location`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location) object with  `pathname` in `Redirect`.

```tsx
const RedirectComp: React.FC<any> = (props: any) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <Redirect to={{ search: location.search, pathname: props.to }} />
  );
}
```